# Use multiple JWT Bearer Authentication For .NET 4.8 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to support multiple JWT Token issuers in .NET 4.8?
I want to provide my API to two different tenants - AzureAD and AzureB2C, so I need my APIs to accept access tokens coming from both AzureAD tenant and AzureB2C tenant.
I find many examples online to do this in .NET Core but no example to do this in .NET 4.8

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to validate multiple JWT Token issuers with Azure AD packages method in .NET framework 4.8. But I think we can do it just by decode the token and check if the `issuer` claim match the value you specified.

In my code, do it like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stream = "your access token";
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(stream) as JwtSecurityToken;

            var iss = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "iss").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(iss);
            //Then check if "iss" matches the value you specified.

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```